# Execute an Excel 2010 Add-In

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, macros

An excel add-in seems to be the easiest way to share a macro I created with my team. I saved the workbook as a .xlam file and installed the add-in so it shows up under the addins button with a checkmark next to the name. However, when I click "OK" nothing happens-- no error message, but the program doesn't run either. Is there anything else I need to do to get the program to execute? Or is the error in my code somewhere? The macro asks the user for input right at the beginning, not sure if that could possibly screw things up? This is my first experience with Visual Basic and add-ins.

Comment: There seems to be some missing details between "..checkmark next.." and "...click OK". Assuming that means you are able to invoke your Add-in and its presenting a dialog with an "OK" button? If not, please expand. To make sure your "OK" function is getting called, add some sanity printouts with: MsgBox "Got here". Best if you could post what you have so far.

Comment: Sorry for being unclear. I select the developer tab, then click Add-Ins from the ribbon. From there I am given small window with a list of add-ins available. I then select my add-in with a check mark and click "OK" to the right. The window then closes and nothing happens. Is there anything else I need to do to get my program to execute?

Comment: Erin, if you want to alert someone, use the at symbol, such as @daverook.

Answer (score 0):

An Excel Add-in is different than Excel macros. If you want to share one or more Excel Macros, [Microsoft has some info about how to do what you really want to do here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/copy-your-macros-to-a-personal-macro-workbook-HA102174076.aspx) for one computer and at the bottom of that article, how to share on multiple computers.

Typically an Excel Add-in would define custom formulas that you could use in a cell, like "=foo(bar)" that would call your code (if you had a function named "foo()"). But Add-In's requires a protocol of registering your formulas. Add-In's also can create UI's, Dialogs and Menus, where each of these can be linked to a macro. Since Excel 2007, these are configured in the XML embedded in the XLAM, not the VBA as was done in previous Excel versions. There is no default UI for macros/Add-Ins, so when you click your Add-In from that menu, it looks for an initialization routine to ask if you to do anything on startup (either during that first click or whenever excel starts with the add-in enabled.) Since nothing is defined, nothing becomes visible.